# capture dialogflow suggestions chip response

Tags: dialogflow-es

May I know how do I get a response using suggestion chips? What should I include in the below code?

```
function buyStatus(agent) {
 ("What is your marital status?")
  agent.add(new Suggestion("Single"));
  agent.add(new Suggestion("Married"));

  // If (.... == "Single") {
       agent.add("You are single");
  } else {
       agent.add("You are married");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow has a more event-like model. The general pattern is

- Your user says or does something to trigger an Intent.
- You handle that Intent in your webhook fulfillment by sending back a reply with `agent.add()`. This includes the message, suggestions, etc.
- You will not know how the user replies until the next time an Intent is called. This may be with one of your suggestions, or may be with their own reply.

Keep in mind that suggestion chips act like the user said or typed what is on the chip. So you will need Intents that match the phrases on the suggestions. Usually you will have a different Intent for each chip, just like you would have different Intents to capture the different things the user might say.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, I need to create a new Intent and all the "Training phrases" have to be the options of my suggestions. And as an Response of this Intense we have a webhook which is capturing the answer and do whatever we want with it. Am I right?

Comment: I've clarified my answer a bit, since the question was focusing more on how you ask, rather than how you setup the Intents to capture the reply. You're mostly correct. The important bit, however, is that you typically setup different Intents to capture different replies.